# OrientDB REST API ignoreError

Tags: rest, orientdb

here is my daily OrientDB question:

Is it possible to ignore errors during the execution of a batch of commands via the REST API?

I am creating edges between nodes with commands like

```
CREATE EDGE ManagedBy FROM (SELECT FROM Employee WHERE account = '<theId>') TO (SELECT FROM Employee WHERE account = '<theId>')
```

The fact is that sometimes the specified accounts are not in the DB, thus I obtain the following error:

```
Error:com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OCommandExecutionException: No edge has been created because no source vertices
```

Since I am fine with the fact that I cannot create some edge, I would like to skip the returned error in order to insert as much edges as possible.

For the moment I'm inserting the edges one by one, I think that using a batch insert would speed up a lot the process.

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: thanks for the propt reply: I get `Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OCommandExecutionException: No edge has been created because no source vertices`

Comment: I don't think you can skip the error. You could create a javascript server function that does the bach insert and there you can check if the target is empy you just skip the edge creation

Comment: I will, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I followed the advice of @wolf4ood: I created an `insert_edge` JS server function which I call for each edge I want to create. 
If the target and source node exist the edge is created, otherwise no action is taken. Here is its body:

```
var g = orient.getGraph();
var fromQ = "SELECT FROM " + fromTable + " WHERE " + fromField + " = '" + fromValue + "';";
var toQ = "SELECT FROM " + toTable + " WHERE " + toField + " = '" + toValue + "';";

var from = g.command('sql', fromQ, []);
var to = g.command('sql', toQ, []);

if(from.length > 0 && to.length > 0) {
    var createQ = "CREATE EDGE " + edgeType + " FROM (SELECT FROM " + fromTable + " WHERE " + fromField + " = '" + fromValue + "')" + " TO (SELECT FROM " + toTable + " WHERE " + toField + " = '" + toValue + "');";

    return g.command('sql', createQ, []);
}

return null;
```

The parameters are `fromTable, fromField, fromValue, sourceTable, sourceField, sourceValue, edgeType`.
I called the function in this way:

```
SELECT insert_edge('Employee', 'account', <theId>, 'Employee', 'account', <theManager>, 'ManagedBy')
```